# parse date time function order format

Tags: r, datetime, datetime-format, lubridate

Format of original input data is like: "1975M01", the variable name is Month.
The way we put the input into POSIXct date-time object is: `parse_date_time(Month, "%Y%m")`.
I wonder why we ignored the 'M'(1975**M**01), like how can the function recognize the year and month and ignore the M in the middle automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I think a pragmatic solution would be to strip the extra character before parsing the date with `lubridate::parse_date`:

```
str_replace("1975M01", "M", " ") |> parse_date("%Y %m")
```

This works also for more complex timestamp formats as in

```
str_replace("20230522x202200", "T", " ") |> parse_date_time("%Y%m%d %H%M%S")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try `as.POSIXct()`. We have no days, though. But probably we want the first day of the month and just `paste` `01` at the end of the string(s). Finally define the `"M"` literally in `format=` string, and of course add `%d`ay,

```
x <- as.POSIXct(paste0('1975M01', '01'), format='%YM%m%d')
x
# [1] "1975-01-01 CET"
```

where

```
class(x)
# [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

.

This should also work with `lubridate` but can't install it.